# Best approach to include header and footer files in smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty3

I just start using smarty. I’m just bit confuse how to joint files together. Simply said I want to join header and footer in other files such as index and post

So I created a header.php and header.tpl and added the code below to header.php

```
$header_template = new Smarty;
$header_template->debugging = false;
$header_template->caching = false;
$header_template->setTemplateDir('./templates/');
$header_template->assign("title", $home_title);
$header_template->assign("description", $output_cities);
$header_template->display('header.tpl');
```

And then I created an index.php and index.tpl file and in index. php added below code

```
include('header.php');
$index_template = new Smarty;
$index_template->debugging = false;
$index_template->caching = false;
$index_template->setTemplateDir('./templates/');
$index_template->assign("posts", $post);
$index_template->display('index.tpl');
```

But in smarty documentation they ask to use `{include file=header.tpl'}`
So I’m not sure whether I’m doing this the correct way. Appreciate any answer that you can give me.

Comment: Funny typo in your first word...

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions haha my bad. Sorry.

Comment: Basicly when using Smarty you should not include part of the page with `include('header.php');`, do all the work in the templates, when its about composing templates

Comment: I like the term: `Beast approach` ;)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions so basically i need to write the whole header and footer php code in all my files?

Answer (score 1):

Do it in this way in `index.php`:

```
$index_template = new Smarty;
$index_template->debugging = false;
$index_template->caching = false;
$index_template->setTemplateDir('./templates/');
$index_template->assign("posts", $post);
$index_template->assign("title", $home_title);//from header.php
$index_template->assign("description", $output_cities);//from header.php
$index_template->display('index.tpl');
```

then in `index.tpl`

```
 {include file='header.tpl'}
 index template code
 {include file='footer.tpl'}
```

You dont need `header.php` or `footer.php`

Maybe you should use better variable names like `header_title` instead of `title`, to prevent overriding.

Comment: ok but seems that i need to write header and footer code in all my other php files. since i cannot include them separately.